# No resource identifier found for attribute 'textcolor' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting constant error in main_activity.
    Error:-
    No resource identifier found for attribute 'textcolor' in package 'android'

The code for main activity is this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<linearlayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <imageview android:id="@+id/imageView_pic" 
               android:layout_gravity="center" 
               android:layout_height="100dp" 
               android:layout_width="100dp">

    <button android:id="@+id/button_selectpic" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:text="Select Picture">

    </button><button android:id="@+id/uploadButton" 
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                     android:text="Click To Upload File">

   <textview android:id="@+id/messageText" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:text="" 
              android:textcolor="#000000" 
              android:textstyle="bold">


   </textview>





 </button>

 </imageview>

 </linearlayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android widget are camel cased, so

1. `imageview` is `ImageView`
2. `textview` is `TextView`

and so on. Also, elements that extends View, such Button, ImageView, TextView can not have children, so you have to close immediately the tag. For instance:

```
  <TextView android:id="@+id/messageText" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:text="" 
              android:textcolor="#000000" 
              android:textstyle="bold" />
```

as correctly pointed out by @DoctorDrive also some attributes are camel-cased,  so `android:textcolor` is `android:textColor` and `android:textstyle="bold"` is `android:textStyle="bold"`

Comment: 3. `textColor` shoud be capted. `textStyle` shoud be capted.

Answer (score 3):

It's `textColor` and `textStyle` instead of `textcolor` and `textstyle`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers given, you're closing a Button after a TextView. Se what blackbelt says about closing tags.

Comment: ... and an ImageView after a Button.